# Capture a image and store it to the SD Card in new folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-camera-intent

I am calling the camera and capturing images, I will have to capture 10 images one by one and store them on SD card before I can set them to the Image view. Please check my below code, it does not set to the image view.

How would I store it on the SD card and retrieve it to set to the image view? How would I name the images before storing?

In the first activity I am calling the camera:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mContext = this;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/testing";

    File xmlDirectory = new File(extStorageDirectory);
    if (!xmlDirectory.exists())
        xmlDirectory.mkdirs();

    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
}

private OnClickListener onBtnClicked = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case PHOTO:
                Intent selectImageIntent = new Intent(first.this,
                        second.class);
                startActivityForResult(selectImageIntent, 1);
                break;
        }
    }
};

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");

            Log.d("*****************",
                    "inside onactivityresult in main activity=" + result);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(result);
            iv1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            iv1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my second activity I am capturing the image and passing it to the first activity:

```
private void init() {
    picturePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Camera/"
            + "test.jpg";
    System.out.println("thumbnail path~~~~~~" + picturePath);
    File file = new File(picturePath);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
}


public void startCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", picturePath);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good Practice to initialize your object inside Other Method.

remove this line  `iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);` from `init()` method and Change your  OnCreate() to Below Way.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
//Initialize here
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);

    mContext = this;
    init();

}
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: @cavallo: can you post your logcat here.

Comment: "it is not a good Practice to initialize your object inside Other Method." - Reason? want to know because I am doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

use this code & put your file name & path, camera will capture the image & store it with given name

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
           if (!APP_FILE_PATH_Media.exists()) 
          {
               APP_FILE_PATH_Media.mkdirs();
          }
         uriSavedImage =new File(APP_FILE_PATH_Media+ "/" +
                    "filename"+ ".jpeg");
       cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(uriSavedImage));
       startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

in onActivityResult() use this code to set imageView

```
try
                 {
                 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 options.inSampleSize = 1;
                 bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uriSavedImage.getAbsolutePath(), options);
                 }
                 catch(Exception ee)
                 {

                 }
```